# Programmatically show android action bar, need help troubleshooting

Tags: android, android-studio

I have my themes.xml file set to NoActionBar but need to show my action bar in 1 activity only, I have tried using `getSupportActionBar().show()`
but the app just crashes. Other alternatives I have tried was changing the theme of the activity in the manifest file but it did not work either. Need some help troubleshooting

**themes.xml file**

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.Test" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

**Portion of android manifest**

```
<activity android:name=".JoinSession" android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.DayNight.ActionBar"/>
```

**Activity which I would like to show action bar**

```
public class JoinSession extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_join_session);
        getSupportActionBar().show();
```

Comment: Use toolbar instead of actionbar.

Answer (score 2):

In your manifest add this line:

```
<application
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
/>
```

In your activity layout file:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
 android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
 android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
 android:elevation="4dp"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
```

In your JoinSession activity:

```
  Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
  setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
```

Comment: This is what I was going to suggest. Toolbar over action bar, especially in the case where you only need it in one activity. This is explained here https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up.

Comment: yup thanks all toolbar did the trick

Comment: You can mark answer as accepted if it worked for you.

Comment: I don't even think elevation is supported for all versions below api level 21